# How to query the column with a keyword name?

Tags: sql, dolphindb

How  to query the column with a keyword name ?

I create a table in which a column named true. I get an error when I select the true column.

```
select true from t
```

The error is:

```
Syntax Error: [line #1] A table column [1] must be assigned a valid name
```

How to query the column of name true?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [sql](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/s/sql.html) function to query, the code is as follows:

```py
sql(sqlCol("true"), t).eval()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just as it says, you cannot have a column named "true" because it is a **private SQL keyword**

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, `true` is a reserved keyword. You can find lists for these depending on the database engine. Like `from`, `select` or `where`, for example, it wouldn't make sense if you had a table named of one of these names. Your query might look like this:

```
select column_name(s)
from where;
```

SQL thinks that you've left out the table name and went straight to the where clause. It's recommended that you choose column and table names that are not keywords. However, if you do, you can simply place the name in backticks.

```
select `true` from t;
```